# FireBase Remote Config вопросы по примению

Tags: android, firebase-android

Возникли вопросы по применению `FireBase Remote Config`. А именно, на данный момент я получаю `default`-значения.

```
 public HashMap<String, Object> getDefaults() {
    HashMap<String, Object> defaults = new HashMap<>();
    defaults.put("nameText", getString(R.string.nameText));
    defaults.put("byWord", getString(R.string.byWord));
    return  defaults;
}
```

И после добавляю

```
         ....
    mFirebaseRemoteConfig.setDefaults(getDefaults());
         ....
```

1. А что если у меня 100+ переменных, слишком разрастается функция и можно упустить несколько слов, и при добавление новых ресурсов, нужно сюда стучать.
2. Сейчас я добавляю в компоненты `yWord.setText(mFirebaseRemoteConfig.getString("byWord"));` . Можно ли как-то внедрять через xml? Опять же разрастаются активити, фраменты.
3. Если используются в программе ресурсы `string-array`. Как можно изменить только один элемент(в 5 или 10 элемент).

Может кто видел статьи или уроки, где затрагиваются такие темы, не стесняйтесь скидывайте))

**Добавление:**
На третий вопрос можно ответить это использовать `JSON`. Вопрос не слишком ли это усложняет код? Если в списке находится 100 элементов, а нужно изменить 1 - 2.  То в `JSON` нужно добавлять все. Хм... Есть другие варианты реализации? 
Возможно идеальный вариант, если можно было передавать название списка, номер элемента которое заменить и значение. Но скорее всего такой возможности нет?